# Ubuntu 18.04 slow boot

Tags: boot

I tried to disable some of the services, but this didn't work out. I'd really appreciate some help on this.

[image]

Comment: Try `critical-chain` instead of `blame` to find out which services are worthwhile to examine. Please paste text instead of attaching images of text.

Comment: ok , i found it , so how can i disable them ? I'm new to linux...

Comment: Define how slow is slow. Do you see any error messages at boot? Does the machine operate normally once booted? What's your configuration? Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Output of `systemd-analyze`.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text, but copy-paste the text instead so it's searchable on Google. Please [edit] your question to reflect this.  **;-)**